# What time zone aliases does node's Date.parse support?

Tags: node.js, date, timezone

While node's `Date.parse` handles numeric timezones like `Date.parse('2015-01-01 00:00 UTC-7')`, it also handles a few aliases like `PST` for Pacific Standard Time. What is the full list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It supports the zones needed for compatibility with [RFC822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-5.1) (superseded by [RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-4.3) and [RFC5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-4.3))

```
 zone        =  "UT"  / "GMT"                ; Universal Time
                                             ; North American : UT
             /  "EST" / "EDT"                ;  Eastern:  - 5/ - 4
             /  "CST" / "CDT"                ;  Central:  - 6/ - 5
             /  "MST" / "MDT"                ;  Mountain: - 7/ - 6
             /  "PST" / "PDT"                ;  Pacific:  - 8/ - 7
```

It also supports `"Z"`, as it's part of [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (and mandated by [ES5.1§15.9.1.15](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15)), and `"UTC"`, as it's an extremely common convention (though interesetingly, not in the spec!)

Note that RFC822 also describes other military time zone abbreviations, lettered `A` through `Z`, but only `Z` is supported.  The others have been deprecated from most implementations.

Also note that time zone abbreviations are not reliable in general.  Specifically, consider that while `"CST"` is defined here as UTC-6, it might be one of 5 different time zones around the world that happen to share the same three letter abbreviation.  See [this list on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations).

Comment: Aha! That explains a lot. Thanks! :-) Presumably these are implemented as constants rather than resolved in locale/regionally dependent ways in node.

Comment: Yes, these are just the edge cases needed for backwards compatibility.  In general, you shouldn't rely on them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where it's defined, but an exhaustive search in the three-letter ASCII namespace:

```
alphabet = []
a = 'A'
while a <= 'Z'
  alphabet.push a
  a = String.fromCharCode a.charCodeAt() + 1

months = 'JAN,FEB,MAR,APR,MAY,JUN,JUL,AUG,SEP,OCT,NOV,DEC'.split ','
tzs = {}

for a in alphabet
  for b in alphabet
    for c in alphabet
      tz = a + b + c
      continue  if tz in months
      try
        t = Date.parse '2015-01-01 00:00:00 ' + tz
        tzs[tz] = (new Date t).toISOString()
        console.log tz, tzs[tz]
```

...suggests it's just a few US ones, and UTC/GMT:

```
CDT 2015-01-01T05:00:00.000Z
CST 2015-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
EDT 2015-01-01T04:00:00.000Z
EST 2015-01-01T05:00:00.000Z
GMT 2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
MDT 2015-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
MST 2015-01-01T07:00:00.000Z
PDT 2015-01-01T07:00:00.000Z
PST 2015-01-01T08:00:00.000Z
UTC 2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
```